# Footnote in booktabs package

Tags: tables, footnotes, booktabs

I wish to add a footnote somewhere in a table. I am using `booktabs` package. I wrote the footnote using `\footnote`. It is showing symbol 1 inside a small box but it is not showing the footnote anywhere.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,latexsym,amscd,amssymb,mathrsfs,hyperref,textcomp,booktabs}
We have already discussed about completeness.   
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\def\arraystretch{1.4}\tabcolsep=2pt\small\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l l @{}}\toprule
Order&Group $G$&Gap Id&Presentation&$\Gamma_d(G)$\footnote{We shall exclude the cases $d=1,|G|$, since $\Gamma_1(G)=K_1=\Gamma_{|G|}(G)$}\\ \midrule
1&$C_1$&1(1)&$\langle a;a^1\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_1)=K_1$ \\
2&$C_2$&2(1)&$\langle a;a^2\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_2)=\Gamma_2(C_2)=K_1$ \\ 
3&$C_3$&3(1)&$\langle a;a^3\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_3)=\Gamma_3(C_3)=K_1$ \\ 
4&$C_4$&4(1)&$\langle a;a^4\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_4)=\Gamma_2(C_4)=\Gamma_4(C_4)=K_1$\\ 
&$C_2\times C_2$&2(2)&$\langle a,b;a^2,b^2,aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(G)=\Gamma_4(G)=K_1,\Gamma_2(G)=K_3$\\ 
5&$C_5$&5(1)&$\langle a;a^5\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_5)=\Gamma_5(C_5)=K_1$\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Abelian groups}
\end{table}
This table shows $\Gamma_d(G)$ for some abelian groups.

\end{document}
```

This is showing the line `This table shows $\Gamma_d(G)$ for some abelian groups.` before the table and table is showing on next page. Also i want the symbol `*` or `\dagger` at the place of `a` and I do not want the line before footnote.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001). There are quite a few ways for introducing footnotes inside a `tabular`(or similar) environment. Please post a Minimum Working Example (MWE, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows what you've tried so far. Please also be specific about *where* you want the footnote text to appear, say at the bottom of the table or at the bottom of the page. You mention that you use the `booktabs` package; that's great! However, how does that relate to generating footnotes in a table?

Comment: You should also have a look at package [threeparttable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable).

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for suggestion. I have modified my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `minipage` for the tabular. However, your tabuloar is too wide and, of course, you shouldn't use too many lines. Without it it makes it more readable:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,latexsym,amscd,amssymb,mathrsfs,hyperref,textcomp,booktabs}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.9cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{4cm}|p{4.5cm}|}
\hline
Order&Group $G$&Gap Id&Presentation&$\Gamma_d(G)$\footnote{We shall exclude the cases $d=1,|G|$, since $\Gamma_1(G)=K_1=\Gamma_{|G|}(G)$}\\ \hline
1&$C_1$&1(1)&$\langle a;a^1\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_1)=K_1$ \\ \hline
2&$C_2$&2(1)&$\langle a;a^2\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_2)=\Gamma_2(C_2)=K_1$ \\ \hline
3&$C_3$&3(1)&$\langle a;a^3\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_3)=\Gamma_3(C_3)=K_1$ \\ \hline
4&$C_4$&4(1)&$\langle a;a^4\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_4)=\Gamma_2(C_4)=\Gamma_4(C_4)=K_1$\\ \cline{2-5}
&$C_2\times C_2$&2(2)&$\langle a,b;a^2,b^2,aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(G)=\Gamma_4(G)=K_1,\Gamma_2(G)=K_3$\\ \hline
5.&$C_5$&5(1)&$\langle a;a^5\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_5)=\Gamma_5(C_5)=K_1$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Abelian groups}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\def\arraystretch{1.4}\tabcolsep=2pt\small\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l l @{}}\toprule
Order&Group $G$&Gap Id&Presentation&$\Gamma_d(G)$\footnote{We shall exclude the cases $d=1,|G|$, since $\Gamma_1(G)=K_1=\Gamma_{|G|}(G)$}\\ \midrule
1&$C_1$&1(1)&$\langle a;a^1\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_1)=K_1$ \\
2&$C_2$&2(1)&$\langle a;a^2\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_2)=\Gamma_2(C_2)=K_1$ \\ 
3&$C_3$&3(1)&$\langle a;a^3\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_3)=\Gamma_3(C_3)=K_1$ \\ 
4&$C_4$&4(1)&$\langle a;a^4\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_4)=\Gamma_2(C_4)=\Gamma_4(C_4)=K_1$\\ 
&$C_2\times C_2$&2(2)&$\langle a,b;a^2,b^2,aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(G)=\Gamma_4(G)=K_1,\Gamma_2(G)=K_3$\\ 
5.&$C_5$&5(1)&$\langle a;a^5\rangle$&$\Gamma_1(C_5)=\Gamma_5(C_5)=K_1$\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Abelian groups}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using your second suggestion but it is showing the table in next page and the matter written after the table is showing before the table. I do not want so. Please tell me how to remove this error.

Comment: update your question with a _complete_ example which shows the problem.

Comment: I have modified my problem.

Comment: you forgot the `\begin{document}` However, I get the same output as in my answer. But you can use `\begin{figure}[!htb]` (The `!` is important).